# Using axios with Node to get a picture jpg

Tags: node.js, axios, http-get, node-rest-client

I'm trying to get a picture [via Node http get request] from another Node app, using axios.
The problem is that when I use axios I get bad format of the file and when I save it, it doesnt
look lime a picture... When I use http get, I get a perfect picture and it is saved well.

- The working code to get the picture:

**The Receiver:**

```
    var data = new Stream.Transform();
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        console.log(typeof chunk)
        data.push(chunk);
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
      fs.writeFileSync('event.png', data.read());
    });
```

**The Sender:**

```
export const getImage =  (req, res) => {
const pathToImage = 'C:/dev/server/images/event.jpg';
const img = fs.readFileSync(pathToImage);

res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'blob' });
res.end(img, 'binary');
}
```

- The axios (not working code):

```js
axios.get(url)
    .then((response: AxiosResponse)=>{
          // save picture locally:
          let data = new Stream.Transform();
          data.push(response.data);
          fs.writeFileSync('event.jpg', data.read());
     })
     .catch((error: AxiosError) => {
         console.log(error.message);
     })
```

Is there any idea why the axios doesn't work like the http ?

Comment: Can you get image with postman?

Comment: Yes, as I said, I can get it using simple http get.

Answer (score 3):

Got it - it is very simple:

```
const response = await axios({
        url,
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'stream'
    })
    fs.writeFileSync('event.png', response.data.read());
```